# Load image from drop down and then play sound when clicked by user based on image selected

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create a communications solution for special needs pupils. The goal is to be able to select two images from drop down menus and then load an image so child can communicate their choice. My goal is when the child clicks on image it will either say what they have chosen or load image selected on new page so person supporting them knows what they have chosen

I have managed to work out how to get the images to load from the drop down menu however I cannot work out how to then associate sound or page link with image selected

```html
    <img id="imageToSwap" src="blank.jpg" />

    <br/><br/>

    <select id="dlist" onChange="swapImage()">
    <option value="blank.jpg"> </option>
    <option value="crisps.jpg">Crisps</option>
    <option value="ricecake.jpg">Rice Cake</option>
    <option value="blueroll.jpg">Blue Roll</option>
    <option value="banana.jpg">Banana</option>
    <option value="orange.jpg">Orange</option>
    <option value="sandwich.jpg">Sandwich</option>
    <option value="chips.jpg">Chips</option>
    <option value="breadstick.jpg">Breadstick</option>
    <option value="drink.jpg">Drink</option>
    <option value="wotsits.jpg">Wotsits</option>
    </select>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    function swapImage(){
     var image = document.getElementById("imageToSwap");
     var dropd = document.getElementById("dlist");
     image.src = dropd.value; 


    };
    </script>
    </td>
    <td>
    <br/>
    <img src="blank.jpg">
    </td>
    <td>

    <img id="imageToSwap1" src="blank.jpg">

    <br/><br/>

    <select id="dlist1" onChange="swap()">
    <option value="blank.jpg"> </option>
    <option value="crisps.jpg">Crisps</option>
    <option value="ricecake.jpg">Rice Cake</option>
    <option value="blueroll.jpg">Blue Roll</option>
    <option value="banana.jpg">Banana</option>
    <option value="orange.jpg">Orange</option>
    <option value="sandwich.jpg">Sandwich</option>
    <option value="chips.jpg">Chips</option>
    <option value="breadstick.jpg">Breadstick</option>
    <option value="drink.jpg">Drink</option>
    <option value="wotsits.jpg">Wotsits</option>
    </select>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    function swap(){
     var image = document.getElementById("imageToSwap1");
     var dropd = document.getElementById("dlist1");
     image.src = dropd.value; 
    };
    </script>
```

Any help to associate sound file that will play on click or link to new page wuld be great

Comment: onclick of the image you want to redirect to another page is it?

Answer (score 0):

Replace your `swapImage()` function with this one.

```
function swapImage() {
    var image = document.getElementById("imageToSwap");
    var dropd = document.getElementById("dlist");
    image.src = dropd.value;    

    // Play sound, simple click sound
    var url = 'https://www.zapsplat.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/sound-effects-18146/zapsplat_multimedia_click_001_19367.mp3';
    var a = new Audio(url);
    a.play();
};
```